# Flutter - how to pass scroll event under Overlay?

Tags: flutter, dart

My scenario is - I have overlayEntry inserted, which stays visible when my mouse hovers it. The overlayEntry itself is created on the screen which is scrollable. When I am trying scrolling by mouse, then it does not scroll because overlayEntry gets all touch events.
Is there any solution which let me still operates in overlayEntry by touch events BUT scroll event will be passed to the "main screen"?

Comment: Is your overlay entry `opaque`?

Comment: @Abion47 no, it uses default "false" value

Comment: Working on the same thing - Did you ever make any progress?. Im curious if this is even doable. I believe the Overlay is a separate route on top of the route you are showing it from (with the scroll view). Right now, I have a fullscreen gesture recognizer that dismisses the overlay and then I can scroll, but thats it.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with tap events, and was able to solve it by wrapping my overlay in an `IgnorePointer` widget. Not sure if this works for scroll events as well?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with a IgnorePointer or MouseRegion (if you need MouseRegion functions) and set "opaque" property to "false".